# How to permanently change sysfs setting for certain block device?

Tags: 14.04, disk, timeout

I have a disk which needs an increased SATA timeout to work properly (at least that's the current workaround, see comments at https://serverfault.com/questions/682061). I figured out that I can set this timeout by doing

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 120 > /sys/block/sda/device/timeout'
```

I can write this into a boot script or use the sysctl interface (right?) by putting this into `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sys.block.sda.device.timeout = 120
```

However, due to my setup this disk might be `sda`, or `sdb` or `sdd` depending on what combinations of disks are available at boot time. So I have to identify it by UUID or label. Unfortunately, /sys only contains pointers to `sdX` and `dm-X` devices, not UUID or LABEL symlinks.

Before I start hacking my own solution: How *should* I uniquely address a block device (disk) in /sys to permanently change a setting like the timeout above?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/373636/91839 (in short: install `sysfsutils` package)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at /sys/block/sda/device.  It is a symlink to a real sysfs path that depends on the pci device ( the sata host controller ) and the port to which the drive is attached, and this isn't going to change unless you physically move the drive connection.